# Translation tool for desktop with glossary

Tags: windows, open-source, translation

At my job I have to translate a lot of text from one language to an other one.
It's a software and procedure manual.
This tool I would like to use it also in future.
I prefer open source.

I'm looking for a tool, where I have one text left (source language), the other right (target language), and a glossary with the given fixed translations. E. g. Names used in the software.

translate.google.com is nice, has no glossary.
deepl.com is fine, the glossary is to expensive for me.

added:
I want open source, because I want to use it later also for my theses papers next year.
The work I spend in my glossary should be usable in future.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record.

I'm using OmegaT now.
Having a word Doc as source, it is not perfect, but it does it's job.